# Apache ignores 'require user'

Tags: apache, svn, permissions, webserver

We are using a berkeley-db for authorisation of svn-access.

We have it configured like that:

```
<Location /svn>
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "svn Authentication"

    AuthBasicProvider dbm
    AuthDBMUserFile /****/userDatabase.db
    AuthDBMType db
    AuthDBMGroupFile /****/userDatabase.db
    AuthzDBMType db

    SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

Until here everything works fine and people gain access according to their respective groups. No I wanted / need to add some specific users to gain (read-only) access to one repository without changing their groups. I tried the following

```
<Location /svn/administration>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /data/svn/administration

    SVNPathAuthz off

    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require group svn-admin-readwrite
   </LimitExcept>

    <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require group svn-admin-read
        Require user testUser testUser2
    </Limit>
</Location>
```

The modules 'authn_dbm' and 'authz_user' are enabled. Anything (obvious) I am missing here? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> Anything (obvious) I am missing here?

Reading (and understanding) some parts of SVN Book, at least ["Per-directory access control"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir) (maybe full chapter ["httpd, the Apache HTTP Server"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html)) and ["Path-Based Authorization"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)

I see at least two weakness in current config

- Without `DAV svn`+`SVNParentPath` in `<Location /svn>` container you must to have for N repositories N+1 `Location` containers and add|remove location for every added|removed repository. Subversion-way is to have **single location** for parent of repository-dirs

> For example, if you know you will be creating multiple Subversion repositories in a directory /var/svn that would be accessed via URLs such as http://my.server.com/svn/repos1, http://my.server.com/svn/repos2, and so on, you could use the httpd.conf configuration syntax in the following example:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn

  # Automatically map any "/svn/foo" URL to repository /var/svn/foo
  SVNParentPath /var/svn
</Location>
```

> Using this syntax, Apache will delegate the handling of all URLs whose path portions begin with /svn/ to the Subversion DAV provider, which will then assume that any items in the directory specified by the SVNParentPath directive are actually Subversion repositories. This is a particularly convenient syntax in that, unlike the use of the SVNPath directive, you don't have to restart Apache to add or remove hosted repositories.

- Path-based ACLs for Subversion in Apache implemented (and used in 99% cases) with `authz_svn_module` and AuthzSVNAccessFile, in which user's and group's access rights (for any repository in tree or part of repo-tree) defined... and also group's membership, which makes AuthDBMGroupFile obsoleted (and Location without LimitExcept & Limit - more compact and readable)